# Cytoscape.js export does not include dynamic/runtime node styling

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

```js
let node = cy.$(`#${res.node}`);
node.style({'background-image': res.url});
node.data('name', `${res.label}`);
```

Exporting the Cytoscape instance parameters via `cy.json()` does not include node styling. I could add `background-image` under `data` of each node and process that upon initializing cy with a previously saved set of params, but that does not seem like a good solution if I have like 6 different style properties that are specific to a node.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Went with storing node-related styling under node `data`. That does indeed get exported.